# Anyone know how to slide in a UIDatePicker like keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, animation, uidatepicker

Does anyone know how to slide in a UIDatePicker with a Done button like the keyboard control? If so, can you share some sample code on how. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a `UIViewController`, and show it modally.

Create `UIViewController` and setup the view with OK-button in Interface Builder, as you would for any view controller.

And display it using:

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController 
                          animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You can set the root views background to clear if you want it transparent. And optionaly animate it to cemi-transparent black when the transition has finished. Something like this would work:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  if (animated) [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeDark" context:NULL];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWithe:0.0f alpha:0.5f];
  if (animated) [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Actually there's a problem with this approach regarding clear modal view controllers.  Just thought I'd point it out for anyone else here who wasted a few hours on this approach.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849458/transparent-modal-view-on-navigation-controller

Answer (score 0):

1.create a subclass of the UIButton class

2.redeclare inputview as read-write

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIView *inputView;
```

3.set canBecomeFirstResponder to YES

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
return YES;
}
```

4.set inputview as datepicker

```
self.inputView = self.datePicker;
```

5.set UIResponder to firstResponder when you want

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

5.you can see datepicker slide in  like keyboard