# iPhone datepicker instead of keyboard?

Tags: iphone, forms, keyboard, uitextfield, uidatepicker

How would you do that?

I have a form with a UITextField. When I click in it I would like to display a UIDatePicker instead of the default Keyboard that pops-up by default? Note that there are also other elements on my form.

Comment: Why not use a UIDatePicker instead of UITextField?

Comment: do you have the code for this? I am facing the same issue as well

Comment: you should really change the selected answer on this.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I think this is a more official way to do this:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init] autorelease];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
datePicker.tag = indexPath.row;
textField.inputView = datePicker;
```

Comment: This is not working for me in iOS 5.  The text field still presents the normal keyboard when clicked.  After setting textField.inputView with a valid pointer and then examining it immediately afterward, it's back to nil.  Anybody have an idea why?  I'm setting it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: check and see if your "datePicker" ivar is not nil

Comment: this is working perfectly fine, but how to hide the date picker after the date has been selected

Comment: @Noor you would just resign the textfield as first responder. eg. [textField resignFirstResponder];

Comment: How would you know that the user has selected the date he wants..? Because there is no OK/DONE button.

Comment: @shashwat You could add a toolbar with a done button as a  inputAccessoryView. Or simply consider the selecting of another field as indication that the user wants to use the selected date.

Answer (score 9):

in .h

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker;
NSDate *date;
UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar;
```

in ViewDidLoad:

```
if (keyboardToolbar == nil) {
    keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    [keyboardToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];

    UIBarButtonItem *extraSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *accept = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Accept" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(closeKeyboard:)];

    [keyboardToolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: extraSpace, accept, nil]];
}

self.txtDate.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar;

datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.txtDate.inputView = datePicker;


- (void)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender{

date = datePicker.date;

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];


[self.txtDate setText:[df stringFromDate:date]];
}
```

in storyboard add to txtDate -> EditingDidEnd

```
- (IBAction)establishHour:(id)sender{

hour = hourPicker.date;

NSDateFormatter *hf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[hf setDateFormat:@"HH:MM"];

[self.txtHour setText:[hf stringFromDate:hour]];

}
```

Sets the keyboard as DatePicker and created a toolbar with a button to accept the selection.

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include how/why this code will solve the problem.

Comment: - (void)cerrarTeclado:(id)sender{
   [self.txtFecha resignFirstResponder];
}

Answer (score 6):

I've converted Johan Kool's answer into swift if anyone would like it. I placed the code in viewDidLoad.

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "datePickerValueChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
textField.inputView = datePicker
```

Comment: Add one more line for iOS 14 and above:
datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels

Answer (score 0):

```
(IBAction)estableceHora:(id)sender{
   Hora = horaPicker.date;
   NSDateFormatter *hf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [hf setDateFormat:@"HH:MM"];
   [self.txtHora setText:[hf stringFromDate:Hora]];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Added in .h files :**

```
UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

**Added in .m files :**

```
{

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

pTxtDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",

[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

NSLog(@"pTxtDate.text %@",pTxtDate.text);

[df release];

[self.view addSubview:pTxtDate]; 

[pTxtDate release];

DatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 325, 300)];

DatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

DatePicker.hidden = NO;

DatePicker.date = [NSDate date];

[DatePicker addTarget:self

  action:@selector(LabelChange:)

forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self.view addSubview:DatePicker];

    [DatePicker release];

}



- (void)LabelChange:(id)sender {

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

pTxtDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",

[df stringFromDate:DatePicker.date]];

}
```

Comment: Please use the built-in UIDatePicker instead of trying to roll your own - it will save you a *lot* of time and pain.