# Using a UIDatePicker instead of Keyboard for UITextField Issues

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, uidatepicker

Hi I am trying to display a `UIDatePicker` instead of a keyboard whenever a `UITextField` is tapped so that the user can give a start and end time for an event.  My code works but not well and not the way I want it to.

My first issue is that whenever you tap on one of the UITextField the `UIDatePicker` only come up the second time the `UITextField` is tapped. Otherwise it shows the original keyboard.

My second issue is that whenever the `UIDatePicker` is edited it only changes the `UITextField` whenever the `UIDatePicker` is edited.  I need the `UITextField` to display the string in the `UIDatePicker` as soon as its opened so that the `UITextField` is up to date with what is going on the `UIDatePicker`.

Here is my current code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
 var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
    StartTimeTextField.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action:
    Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    var datePickerView2  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView2.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
    EndTimeTextField.inputView = datePickerView2
    datePickerView2.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker2:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh mm am pm"
    StartTimeTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}



func handleDatePicker2(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh mm am pm"
    EndTimeTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777237/iphone-datepicker-instead-of-keyboard

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati  That would work but I don't really understand Objective - C. Thanks though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why you are changing keyboard by the action!

Just add your code in `viewDidLoad` :

```
var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
StartTimeTextField.inputView = datePickerView
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
EndTimeTextField.inputView = datePickerView
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker2:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

and remove that methods like

```
@IBAction func
```

Comment: For some reason nothing is happening.  The UIDatePicker isn't coming up at all

Comment: @TripPhillips did you removed the action ? from textfield ?

Comment: @TripPhillips this is perfect, If you are using simulator then sometimes keyboard doesn't come up. so, press COMMAND+K.

Comment: @TripPhillips I have updated answer for that. hope it help you

Comment: Im using my iPhone.  I can't figure it out tonight but hopefully I can in the morning if the code is perfect.  Thanks for the help. I will let you know whenever I figure it out.

Comment: Ok so I tried it in a new project and it worked so now I need to figure out how to do it in mine.

Comment: @TripPhillips Welcome :)