# How to make a custom data input view in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, healthkit

I would like to make a custom data input field similar to the [Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777237/iphone-datepicker-instead-of-keyboard) function. However, I would like the input field to display different height selections. This same effect/function is mimicked in the IOS 9 health app - Height and Weight entry pages.

So essentially I am making a datePicker style input view only it displays measurements instead of the date.

How can I achieve this, and do I need to use the Health Kit framework for this?

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for `UIPicker`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/

Comment: You should refer [Tutorial point's tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_picker.htm) or [Techotopia's tutorial]
(http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_UIPickerView_Example). You need to just `UIPickerView` to get desired output. Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UIDatePicker` is a specialized example of a `UIPickerView`. (For reasons I've never fully understand, it doesn't inherit from `UIPickerView`. It seems like it should.)

Anyway, what you want to do is to set up a `UIPickerView` that has entries for as many components as you need (If you want the user to be able to enter feet an inches, for example, you would create a component for feet and another component for inches. If you were using the Metric system it would probably make sense to just let the user input a measurement as a pure number of meters, since any metric measurement can be cleanly expressed in meters.)

You should be able to find a sample of using `UIPickerView` online somewhere.