# push uiviewcontroller from presentModalViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I Show a view using `presentModalViewController`. and from this `UIView` I want to push a `UIView` using `UINavigationController`. 
I tried below code for this

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController 
                pushViewController:objViewFullScreen 
                          animated:YES];
```

But it did not works for me. so please can any one suggest how I push a view from `ModelViewController`.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you have to present your modal view controller inside a navigation controller:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNib" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];

[vc release];
[nc release];
```

Then inside `MyViewController` you can do:

```
OtherViewController *vc = [[OtherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyOtherNib" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. it works for me. but the vc view is not transparent. i also set the [uicolor clearcolor] but it not works for me. so can you suggest me how i make it transparent. Thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849458/transparent-modal-view-on-navigation-controller/859215#859215

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)pushViewControllerWithCustomAnimation:(UIViewController *)newViewController {
    newViewController.view.alpha = 0.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:newViewController.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                     animations:^{
                         newViewController.view.alpha = 1;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL fin){
                         if (fin) {
                             // finally display the new viewcontroller for real
                             [self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:NO];
                         }
                     }];
}
```