# Transparent modalViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transparent Modal View on Navigation Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849458/transparent-modal-view-on-navigation-controller)

I want to make my viewController with transparent `backgroundColor` but i don't have any luck..

I've tried to set/use...

- `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` - still I have white colored background.
- `self.view.alpha = .0f`; - all my thing in my VC are missing but i still have white background
- `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:.7f]` and still white background below my transparent view.

EDIT1:

Tested on:

- iPad3, iOS 6.0
- iPad 6.0 Simulator

Comment: Are you trying to set it transparent so that the view you present it over is shown?

Comment: Yes. The ViewController below must be visible, partially of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After little more researching I've found this approach:

Original code:

```
MyViewController *popUpViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:popUpViewController animated:YES];
[popUpViewController release];
```

Modified code:

```
TTPopUpViewController *popUpViewController = [[TTPopUpViewController alloc] init];
popUpViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:popUpViewController animated:YES];
[popUpViewController release];
```

So as you can see i've using `modalPresentationStyle` property on my ViewController which I wan't to present, right before call `presentModalViewController:animated:`

NOTE: My ViewController view have size of {680, 700}

It present my ViewController view with size of `{540, 620}` and because my original size bigger I have parts my borders and shadows hidden but with little modification of my view look and feel it will be okay.

However this approach seems to give me what I want.

========

For more information please refer to following Apple documentation:

[UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIModalPresentationFullScreen)

Answer (score 1):

Generally not possible using presentModalViewController.  Here's a similar question with a workaround:

[Transparent Modal View on Navigation Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849458/transparent-modal-view-on-navigation-controller)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you are doing is that the ViewController's view below the transparent one is removed from the screen after presenting the new ViewController. Manually adding a new view on top of the current ViewController and setting that to transparent will work though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use presentViewController to achieve this, however there's a way - which is not very elegant.

```
.h file
@propert(strong,nonatomic) MyCustomViewController *myCustomVC;

.m file
-(void) presentTransparentViewController
{
if(self.myCustomVC==nil) {
    _myCustomVC = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] init];
    }

self.myCustomVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIView *view = self.myCustomVC.view;
view.opaque = NO;

view.frame = self.view.frame; //assuming the views are the same size
[self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

You can also add the view below the main screens frame and present it with an animation.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a workaround for that. Just create a 1X1 of UIViewController and add it to your parent view controller. And show the modal view controller in that UIViewController.

on viewDidLoad;

```
self.dummyViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
 [self.dummyViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
 [self.view addSubView:self.dummyViewController.view];
```

when you need to open a transparentViewController;

```
[self.dummyViewController presentModalViewController:yourTransparentModalViewController animated:true];
```