# UITextField attributedPlaceholder color and opacity in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsattributedstringkey

I have custom `textField` which has `@IBInspectable` property `placeHolderColor: UIColor` and it works fine. I set it by:

```
attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeHolder, attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: placeHolderColor])
```

How can I set programmatically an opacity value for this property only, not for normal text in my textfield ? I didn't find any matching `NSAttributedStringKey` to do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIColor` class methods `withAlphaComponent(alpha: )` to set a color alpha. [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24335602/6822622)

```
@IBInspectable var placeholderTextColor: UIColor? {
    set {
        guard let color = newValue else { return }

        let placeholderText = self.placeholder ?? ""
        attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderText, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color.withAlphaComponent(alpha: self.alpha)])
    }
    get{
        return self.placeholderTextColor
    }
}
```

in Swift 4.2

```
attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderText, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color.withAlphaComponent(self.alpha)])
```

Comment: In Swift 4.2.1 the answer above will prompt "Type 'NSAttributedStringKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'foregroundColor'".
Instead, try:
attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderText, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color.withAlphaComponent(alpha: self.alpha)])
Taken from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50325874/2854529

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5**

I used this to change the color without inputing a new `String` for placeholder

```
textField.attributedPlaceholder =  NSAttributedString(string: textField.text!, attributes:
[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor."Your preferred color"])
```