# Type 'NSAttributedStringKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'foregroundColor'

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, swift4.1, nsattributedstringkey

Below is line of code for the above mentioned issue. 
This issue is occurred in `Swift 4.1`.

```
let textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
```

Answer (score 3):

I've fixed this problem by replacing the Key for Attributed String.

Here is my updated Code is:

```
let textAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
```