# Make a popup in Sprite kit in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game in sprite kit with swift, when the game over, I want to make a popup appear for viewing scores and re-play. How can I do that? I made that like a SKNode but I think it is not a good way to do when I have too many Node in the popup.

Answer (score 2):

You could use UIKit. So you could show a [semi-transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849458/transparent-modal-view-on-navigation-controller) `ModalViewController` if the game is over. That way you can use the Storyboard to design it. Also you can design it in to fit the design of your game and don't have to handle the touches in your `touchesBegan` method but you can use UIButtons etc.